# How to Select values from a lookup

Tags: javascript, dynamic, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm new to to CRM.

I have a look-up.  I want to retrieve the **column records** of the selected lookup.
I tried with this, getting only selected lookup `name`, `id`

```
var lookupObject = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("schemaname");

if (lookupObject != null) 
{

    var lookUpObjectValue = lookupObject.getValue();

    if ((lookUpObjectValue != null))         
    {
     var lookuptextvalue = lookUpObjectValue[0].name;
     var lookupid = lookUpObjectValue[0].id;
     }

  }
```

How do I get the other column values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lookup field contains only the `id`,`name` and `entityType` properties.

If you want to retrieve other fields of the selected record you need to call the CRM webservices (in this case is enough to use the `REST` endpoint)

You can find an example here:

http://www.crmanswers.net/2013/07/set-accounts-primary-contact-as.html

and here:

http://www.crmanswers.net/2013/04/get-current-users-full-name-with.html

Note that when you use the `REST` endpoint you need to look for the Schema name. For example the field name is `FullName` and not `fullname`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
var lookupObject = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("schemaname");

if (lookupObject != null) 
{
    var selectedrecordvalues = lookupObject.getValue()[0].keyValues;
    //key values will come as array.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `Json.parse()` from my object lookup and store the value in a variable. example:

```
accountJson = JSON.parse(accountid[0].keyValues);
accountid.name.value;
```